# C: attempting to invert the order of 10 words in a matrix

Tags: c, string, loops, matrix, parameters

I have a matrix of 10 lines and 20 columns; so I ask the user to enter with 10 words and put each word in one line of the matrix. In the next step, I must create another matrix (with the same proportions) in a way that the first word of the first matrix is at the last word of the second matrix, the second word of the first matrix is at the penultimate word of the second matrix, and so on.

But I'm getting some problems with the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


 int main() {
    char str[10][20], str2[10][20];
    int i, j=9;

    /* filling the first matrix */
    for(i =0;i <10;i++){
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
    }

    /* copying to the second matrix in an inverted order */
    for (i=0;i<10;i++, j--){
        str2[i] = str[j];
    }


return 0;

 }
```

It returns the following error: incompatyble types when assigning to type 'char[20]'from type 'char*'

at the line:
"str2[i] = str[j]"

Ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `strcpy`.

Comment: Hm, got it! But, shouldn't this code works? I'm copying the string's pointers to the second matrix in an inverted order, am not i?

Comment: If you declare `str2` as an array of pointers, then yes. In other words, if you declare `str2` as `char *str2[10];` then the code will copy the pointers as you expected.

Comment: So, are you saying that if I state "char str2[10][20]", str2 is not a pointer for char pointers? And if I state "char str[10]", str isn't a pointer??

Comment: Useful took for C declaration: [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org/).  `char str2[10][20]` --> "declare str2 as array 10 of array 20 of char".  BTW: Well formed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say

```
char str2[10][20];
```

then `str2` is a two dimensional array of chars, specifically it is 200 chars arranged in 10 rows of 20 chars.

If you declare `str2` that way, then `str2[i]` is equivalent to a pointer to a `char`, but it is **not an assignable pointer**.  In other words, that pointer can only be used on the right side of an equals sign, not the left side of an equals sign.

If you want an array of pointers, you must declare the array as

```
char *str2[10];
```

In this case, `str2` is a one dimensional array of pointers-to-char. Specifically it is an array of 10 pointers (which will occupy 40 bytes of memory on a 32-bit machine).

So there's the distinction, `char str2[10][20]` occupies 200 bytes of memory and has no assignable pointers, whereas `char *str2[10]` occupies 40 bytes of memory and has 10 assignable pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In c you cannot write(assign) to arrays in their entirety, like the commentor said you should use strcopy (memcpy if its not strings) for this purpose.